# How to validate my datepicker textbox?

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp, datepicker

I'm have a form which contains a date picker and I need to make it a required field for the users. I have a validation for the form, however, it still says that I need to fill in the date everytime I click on the submit button. Am I missing anything?

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="contactForm" action="PostFoundItem" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="dateFound" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Date Found:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar">
                    </i>
                </div>
                <input class="form-control hasDatepicker"  id="fi"  name="dateFound" placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD" type="text"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://formden.com/static/cdn/bootstrap-iso.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://formden.com/static/cdn/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var date_input = $('input[name="dateFound"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
    var container = $('.bootstrap-iso form').length > 0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
    var FromEndDate = new Date();
    date_input.datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
        container: container,
        endDate: '+0d',
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
        required: true,

    })
})
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#contactForm').bootstrapValidator({
            container: '#message',
            fields: {
                dateFound: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The `Date Found` field is required and cannot be empty'
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing jQuery and Bootstrap javascript, do add this in your code

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```